# Binning continuos variables in columns based on time of first column

Tags: python

I am trying to bin values in columns as the average of 5 rows from 1-5, 6-10 and so on using python.
My df dataset looks like this:

```
Unnamed: 0   C00_zscore  C01_zscore  C02_zscore
1   3   5   6
2   4   36  65
3   56  98  62
4   89  52  35
5   32  74  30
6   55  22  35
7   68  23  31
8   97  65  15
9   2   68  1
10  13  54  300
11
```

Ideally, the result should look like this:

```
bin C00_binned  C01_binned  C02_binned
1   36.8        53            39.6
2   47          46.4          76.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the index and divide it by the bin size. This will be the row's bin. In your case, the row number starts at 1 and you want bins of size 5.

```
bin_num = row_num / (bin_size + 1)
```

Now that each row has a `bin_num`, group by it then do the calculations.

```
df['bin_num'] = df['Unnamed'] / 6
df.groupby(['bin_num']).mean()
```

Comment: where do I declare row_num and bin_size?